# Unable to use MergeDelayError

Tags: android, observable, retrofit, rx-java2, rx-android

I have an array of values which I need to post to an api link. The approach till now was to loop through each element and then post it. However, I am migrating the code to rxJava and retrofit. I tried implementing the below-mentioned code to do the task, but I am getting the error "None of the functions can be called with the arguments supplied"

```
Observable.mergeDelayError(Observable.fromIterable(schedules)
                .map { 'Retrofit API call' })
```

I noticed that mergeDelayError required `Iterable<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources`, whereas `Observable.fromIterable(schedules)` returns of type `<T> Observable<T>`. Is there any other way to implement this with `mergeDelayError`. If not, are there any other alternative? The reason I chose this approach was to get a handle on any error that comes up while posting each item of the list to the API. Any help would be much appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your original code ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a compile issue, because you pass in an Observable, where a Iterable of ObservableSource is required.

Please have a look at following solution:

First of all you need to create a Iterable (List) of ObservableSources and then pass it to mergeDelayError.

```
@Test
fun whatever() {
    val reqHandlerImpl = ReqHandlerImpl()

    val schedules = listOf("req1", "req2", "req3")

    // create Iterable of Observables, which will call Retrofit, when subscribed to
    val observables: List<Observable<String>> = schedules.map { reqHandlerImpl.req(it) }

    val merged = Observable.mergeDelayError(observables)

    merged.test().assertValueSequence(schedules)
}

interface ReqHandler {
    fun req(uri: String): Observable<String>
}

class ReqHandlerImpl : ReqHandler {
    override fun req(uri: String): Observable<String> {
        return Observable.just(uri)
    }
}
```